# System python is a lot slower than a virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, performance, virtualenv

Certain python apps to take a lot longer to start up when running via the system python vs a virtualenv.

I've tested this by creating a clean virtualenv, and installing+running apps such as `khal` and `todoman` from it. They take about 200ms to run from a virtualenv, but 1s to run from the system python (installed via my package manager).

I though this might be something specific to me, but I've seen other users report the same issue with both apps, amongst others.

I tried using `cProfile` when running the system python, but it reports that it took just 0.2s -- it seems the other 0.8s are python's startup time and not measured by `cProfile` (which is actually a python module).

I also tried measuring time for simpler, very basic scripts (ie: that just print "hello"), but this does not apply; they run in 0.1s in both the system python and virtualenv).

Comment: Chances are that this is related to imported modules doing heavy work at import time. If those modules are imported conditionally (i.e. only used if available), the large amount of modules in your system Python vs. the reduced set in a virtualenv created with `--no-site-packages` might be responsible for the difference.

Comment: I also noticed that both the `khal` and `todoman` apps seem to use the [`click` CLI framework](http://click.pocoo.org/5/). And when I look at [`todoman/cli.py`](https://github.com/pimutils/todoman/blob/master/todoman/cli.py) for example, there seems to be heavy use of decorators, which *will* be evaluated at import time. In that module, I also spotted at least two `try..except`s ([1](https://github.com/pimutils/todoman/blob/master/todoman/cli.py#L85-L89), [2](https://github.com/pimutils/todoman/blob/master/todoman/cli.py#L123-L128)) that might lead to a different code path at import time.

Comment: In order to confirm/reject my hunch regarding module imports, you could try to clean out your system Python's `site-packages`. **Back up** its original state, and then move out all the packages to a temporary location. Invoke `todoman`. First, you'll get import errors caused by missing *required* dependencies. Move those back in place. If my hunch is right, at that point you should see similar timings as when invoked in your virtualenv. You could then start moving groups of packages back into place binary-search style to track down the culprit.

Comment: The virtualenv I created had todoman and all its dependencies, so the imported modules should be the same (regardless of the conditional imports). The decorator should be irrelevant, because a virtualenv python should run those just as slow as the system python.

Comment: I tried creating a virtualenv with all the system packages installed (except pygobject, which can't be installed in virtualenvs, but is irrelevant here), and the result is the same: virtualenv is 200ms, system is 1s. This is basically a mirror of the "remove the system `site-package`" test (but that one would actually break my system).